# finding the limits of my variables given a constrained

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

Suppose $T$ is a region bounded by $ z = x^2 + y^2 $ and $z = 1 - x^2 - y^2$.

I know they intersect at $2x^2 + 2y^2 = 1 $ which is a circle of radius $1/4$. Also, we see $0 \leq z \leq 1 $. Also, we have

$$ - \sqrt{ 1/2 - x^2 } \leq y \leq \sqrt{1/2 - x^2 } $$
$$ - \sqrt{ 1/2 - y^2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{1/2 - y^2} $$

are these correct bounds for my variables $x,y,z$? thanks

Added: My goal is to compute

$$ \int \int  \int_T \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dxdydz $$

So I need to find the bounds for $T$. But,with this bounds that I found the integral looks very hard to compute.

Comment: The radius is $\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$

Comment: Or $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approaching the problem like this won't get you far, so the question of your integration bounds being correct or not is somehow irrelevant. It is better to resort to a change of variables and perform integration in *cylindrical variables*. In order to do this, let $x = r \cos u$ and $y = r \sin u$, with $z$ staying unchanged, the domain for $(r, u)$ being $(0, \infty) \times (0, 2 \pi)$. The two surfaces (they are paraboloids) that delimit your domain of integration become $z = r^2$ and $z = 1 - r^2$. Notice that not only are they easier to write (and work with), but you also have the advantage of getting rid of $u$ (because the domain of integration is rotationally invariant around the $z$ axis).

The two surfaces intersect when $r^2 = 1 - r^2$, which means $r = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ (because $r$ must be positive), so this means that $0 < r \le \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$. For each such $r$, $z$ varies between $r^2$ and $1-r^2$. This means that your integral becomes

$$\int \limits _0 ^{2\pi} \int \limits _0 ^{\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}} \int \limits _{r^2} ^{1-r^2} \frac {r \cos u} {r^2} r \ \Bbb d z \ \Bbb d r \ \Bbb d u ,$$

where the $r$ after the fraction is the modulus of the Jacobian of the change of variables. Performing the integral in $u$ first gives us the result $0$, because $\int _0 ^{2\pi} \cos u \ \Bbb d u = \sin u \big| _0 ^{2\pi} = 0$, so it becomes unnecessary to compute the remaining two integrals. The final result will be $0$.